# Physical meaning of n!/k!

Tags: combinatorics

Assume $n,k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $k < n$. Does $\frac{n!}{k!}$ have any physical meaning?

What I mean is this, $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$, can be interpreted as $n$ choose $k$ is there any physical interpretation of $\frac{n!}{k!}$.

Comment: Permutation $n-k$ object of $n$ object!

Comment: I mean, it's fairly easy to come up with specific situations where this quantity has value. For example, permutations of $n$ objects, $k$ of which are indistinguishable from one another.

Comment: The number of ways to choose an ordered selection of $n-k$ objects from a set of $n$ objects.

Comment: The conventional term for what you refer to as "physical" is "combinatorial".

Answer (score 0):

The difference between $\dfrac{n!}{k!}$ and $\dfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ is whether we mind order of selection or not (the former one is often referred to as permutation). For example let we have a deck of cards. The number of cases to draw out four spades from spades and hearts without considering the order of selection is $\dfrac{26!}{4!22!}$ e.g. the cases $A\spadesuit,Q\spadesuit,7\spadesuit,2\spadesuit$ and $Q\spadesuit,2\spadesuit,A\spadesuit,7\spadesuit$ are the same but if considering these two latter cases as different the number of cases would be $\dfrac{26!}{22!}$